# $watch not firing when testing using Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, testing, jasmine

I am trying to test my `$watch` listener, however, it's not firing in the test.

Here's the test:

```
it('should fire $watch when selectedBrands change', function() {
    spyOn($scope, 'updateFilters')

    $scope.selectedBrands = ['1'];

    expect($scope.updateFilters).toHaveBeenCalled();
})
```

And the controller:

```
$scope.selectedBrands = [];

$scope.$watch("selectedBrands", function() {
    $scope.updateFilters();
}, true);
```

Finally, the error:

```
Chrome 35.0.1916 (Mac OS X 10.10.0) ItemsController should fire $watch when selectedBrands change FAILED
    Expected spy updateFilters to have been called.
    Error: Expected spy updateFilters to have been called.
        at null.<anonymous> (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/cloqet_client/testing/tests/ItemModule/ItemsController_spec.js:62:38)
```

I tried using `$scope.$digest()` but that makes the test pass even without changing `$scope.selectedBrands`.

Why is the `$watch` not being fired?

Comment: Found anything interesting in the answers below ?

Answer (score 3):

It's correct to use `$scope.$digest()` to trigger the digest.

```
it('should fire $watch when selectedBrands change', function() {
    spyOn($scope, 'updateFilters')

    $scope.selectedBrands = ['1'];

    $scope.$digest();

    expect($scope.updateFilters).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

> but that makes the test pass even without changing
>   $scope.selectedBrands

The reason is $watch **always** fires the first time with `undefined` even you don't change the value. The current test **reflects the correct behavior of your current code**. It means that **your code has a bug that needs to be fixed**.

To fix this, try fixing your code:

```
$scope.$watch("selectedBrands", function(value) {
    if (value){ //check for undefined fired the first time.
       $scope.updateFilters();
    }
}, true);
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/6AJd17paXM2FfUfTYMdL?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Tests run outside of the Angular-context, so there is no automatic $digest cycle happening.
`$watch()` is not fired because you need to first invoke a $digest cycle manually.

You should also keep in mind that every $watch callback is executed once to initialize the value.
That is why your `$scope.updateFilter()` gets called even without changing `selectedBrands`.
Quoting **[the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24watch)**:
*"After a watcher is registered with the scope, the `listener` fn is called asynchronously (via [$evalAsync](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24evalAsync)) to initialize the watcher."*

The proper way to test this, is to manually invoke a $digest cycle (so the the $watch is initiaized), then change `selectedBrands` and finally invoke a secod $digest cycle to "digest" that change.

E.g.:

```
it('should fire $watch when selectedBrands change', function() {
    $scope.$digest();

    spyOn($scope, 'updateFilters');
    $scope.selectedBrands = ['1'];
    $scope.$digest();

    expect($scope.updateFilters).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/LXCHd/)**.

Answer (score 0):

you need a digest process to get fired, that's when watchers do checks

```
it('should fire $watch when selectedBrands change', function() {
    spyOn($scope, 'updateFilters')

    $scope.selectedBrands = ['1'];
    $scope.$digest()

    expect($scope.updateFilters).toHaveBeenCalled();
})
```